# GruntJS CSS handling : How to select CSS files and how to package them

Tags: css, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm using the `Yeoman` stack to bootstrap an application and had a question on how CSS files should be handled. (I've uploaded a sample on Github : https://github.com/ddewaele/jQueryDataTablesGrunt)

The basic question is : How do you go about handling different CSS files

- during development (when running `grunt serve`)
- when packaging the app (when running `grunt build`).

I have installed a number of libraries through bower that come with CSS files.

For example the jQueryDataTables library has the following CSS

```
bower_components/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css
```

Now, the way I understand it is that I should never reference this jquery.dataTables.css file directly in my index.html (I hope this assumption is correct).

My index.html should only contain

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
```

I assume that this styles/main.css will be generated by the grunt workflow and will be correct both in dev mode, as well as in dist mode.

I'm puzzled by a couple of things

- How should I tell grunt that I need to include for example bower_components/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css
- Do I do need to reference that jquery.dataTables.css in my index.html, or in my Gruntfile.js, or simply drop it in app.styles ?
- How does grunt decide what CSS files it needs to assemble into a single main.css
- How does grunts behavior differ between grunt serve and grunt serve dist

Here's what I found :

### grunt serve

When calling `grunt serve` , a CSS file is generated called `.tmp/styles/main.css`,
That is in fact the CSS file that is used by the app when it launched by 'grunt serve'.
That main.css file only contains stuff coming from the `app/styles/main.scss` file.
Other CSS files that are put in app/styles/ are not being picked up by `grunt serve`.

### grunt serve:dist

When calling `grunt serve:dist`, a CSS file is generated called `dist/styles/2314bw1.main.css`
That is in fact the CSS file that is used by the app when it launched by `grunt serve:dist`.
That main.css file contains everything that it found in app/styles/*.css,

So the basic issue is that when running `grunt serve` , the generated main.css **does not** all the classes from all the css files found in app/styles/*.css.

However, when packaging the app `grunt build` or `grunt serve:dist`, it does contain all classes from all the css files found in app/styles/*.css.

How do I configure my app / grunt to use these external CSS, and how do I get to a situation that works during development, as well as during packaging.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Yeoman but it look likes it's running gruntjs underneath. You can edit the tasks to include plugin specific styles.

[This is your gruntfile.js](https://github.com/ddewaele/jQueryDataTablesGrunt/blob/master/Gruntfile.js)

> How does grunt decide what CSS files it needs to assemble into a single main.css ?

Drop your plugin specfic styles inside "app/styles". You can give it a special folder if you want to. Then add to your main.scss. Sass will compile everything down in the main.css.

First in console:

```
cp jquery.dataTables.css jquery.dataTables.scss
```

Then add the import into main.scss

```
@import "jquery.dataTables"
```

> How does grunts behavior differ between grunt serve and grunt serve dist?

serve:dist does this(see code below), it builds your files, opens a link to your server, creates a dummy webserver to serve your files using connect

```
 if (target === 'dist') {
   return grunt.task.run(['build', 'open:server', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
 }
```

serve on the other hand watches changes to your files.

Comment: Yeoman is a collection of tools. Part of it is yo (scaffolding tool) that generates the Gruntfile.js I'm using and the overall project structure. I tried added the import like you mentioned in app/styles/main.scss but the generated /.tmp/main.css still doesn't include anything from the datatables css. I do see the import statement there. But when you distribute your app there is no bower_components folder anymore. So how would that import stil work ?

Comment: Feel free to log a pull request on Github. But adding that import in app/styles/main.scss results in Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/styles/jquery.dataTables.css when running grunt serve. Also are you sure you can import a regular css file using a @import in main.scss ?

Comment: Found something that works now. Updated the code in the Github project. Updated the README.md with the solution (CSS Dependencies section). Feel free to review.

Comment: Sass doesn't copy the file in on @import on a straight css file but you can just change the extension to scss and it should work as intended.

Comment: Would it be considered good practice to change the extension ? Wouldn't that be more of a workaround ?